# How do you program popovers in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do you program popovers in twitter-bootstrap? I'm looking for a step by step set of instructions for activating the popover with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have knowledge yet about JavaScript, but here's how I managed to implement the bootstrap popover.

Make sure your document had linked up with the popover plugin and the tooltip plugin, if not then make a link to those files using the following:

```
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```

Insert the above codes just above the closing body tag, like so:

```
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Then insert this script above the closing body tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {$("a.pop").popover({ animation: true, placement: 'left', trigger: 'hover' })});
```

So all in all, the codes you pasted shall look like this:

```
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
      $("a.pop").popover({ animation: true, placement: 'left', trigger: 'hover' })});
    </script>

    </body>
```

Now, markup your anchor tags for pop functionality. Like so:

```
<a href="#" class="pop" title="Pop!" data-content="Some Content">
```

Explanation, `data-content=""` holds the content of the popover. `title="Pop!"` holds the heading title.

The `class="pop"` is any class name of your choice, but be sure to match the name with the class name found in the script above, that is, `$("a.pop")`

If you prefer to use a id, then It shall be like so,

```
 <a href="#" id="pop" title="Pop!" data-content="Some Content">
```

and...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
      $("a#pop").popover({ animation: true, placement: 'left', trigger: 'hover' })});
    </script>
```

This sample code shall render a left popover, If you want to pop it over to other sides, then change placement: 'left' to i.e. placement: 'top'

Answer (score 2):

I took it from the source code of bootstrap example page:

```
$(function () {
  $("a[rel=popover]")
    .popover({
      offset: 10,
      html: true
    })
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })
})
```

You also could try change this

```
$("a[rel=popover]")
```

to the element that should show the popover.